# How to limit nginx processes on kubernetes worker node?

Tags: kubernetes

Changing worker_process to auto in nginx configuration letting nginx to use all available CPUs of node.

In case of pods where we are limiting nginx to use only 2 CPU, it is expected that setting worker_process will use only 2 CPU but instead of that it is using all available node CPU.
Is this expected behaviour in case of pods?

Comment: Can you share how you have limit the pod to use 2 CPUs as well how you have configured worker_process?

Comment: Kubernetes YAML definition,resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 2
              memory: 1Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 1Gi

Comment: nginx.conf --- worker_process auto; worker_cpu_affinity auto;

Answer (score 0):

When resource limits are defined, Kubernetes makes sure to provide only that limited quota of CPU and memory for the container.

> A container cannot use more than its share of CPU time during this interval.

So, even if the container tries to use more; it will be restricted.

Comment: No that is not happening with nginx pod. As soon worker_process change to auto there is no restriction it is using all available CPU cores rather following limit value which is defined in pod definition.

Comment: Can you share more info on how you have checked the cpu usage of the pod and the container?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can setup a nginx.conf from configmap, and set worker_process from there.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/testing-performance-nginx-ingress-controller-kubernetes/  FYI